# jquery load into a div is so slow as compare to loading a page in an ifram

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load a page (located on the same domain) into a div, using load function by using the following code:.

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
      $("#webContent").load(url);
  });
```

its loading the page, but its too slow. it is loading each and every element of the page one by one, as i can see it in the firebug.

but if i am trying to load the same page inside an iframe, then its loading so fast. i think its loading aysc.

can anyone please explain the difference and the solution to download it into a div. i dont want to use iframe.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

So, what have you tried? This:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#webContent").load(url);
});
```

And this, right?

```
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

Why the javascript solution is slower you ask?

Iframe starts loading right after the html got parsed to the place where your iframe is.

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

The answer is **NO**, you can't make the JavaScript solution faster in this case.

There is a little test if you want it to show that there is no iframe-related speed bonuses over ajax:

Code for the first test case:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#webContent").load(url);
});
```

Code for the second test case:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#webContent").html('<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
});
```

Time needed to load the page will be approximately the same in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: @Andrew `Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.` 

This cannot explain why event like click to .load() still takes orders of magnitude longer than just going to url even after DOM loaded 5 minutes ago.